# Bad format when i put an image to azure blob storage with XMLHttpRequest and SAS

Tags: javascript, azure, xmlhttprequest, blob, storage

I have set up in an SPA application the ability to send files to Azure Blob Storage.

To do this I used XMLHttpRequest and FormData (my users are on computers managed by my company and all have access to HTML5).
 
In order to manage security, the sending of each file is preceded by a call to a method of a Web Api to obtain the shared access signature.

I forward the Content-Type of the file as well as other information to headers.

Everything happens for the better, the files are correctly sent and saved in Azure Blob Storage, but during the transfer, the image files seem to be "altered".

They are well present, I can download them and read them after the download, but I can not open them directly from an img tag.

On the other hand if I send the same image file via Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, there is no problem, the image is well recognized in the img tag.
However, in one case as in the other, the content-type is marked as "image / jpeg". The only noticeable difference is that the MD5 is not the same between these 2 mailings while it is the same file of origin.

From my findings it seems that there is text added to the beginning and the end of the file when sending via XMLHttpRequest.

I explain my code so that you can guide me:
Note 1 : I use typescript (but a javascript solution will suit me) and Promise.
Note 2 : I have resolve all the CORS problems.
Note 3 : I'm using Azure Storage Emulator, but i try with the normal Azure service and the problem is the same.

Here is the text added in the image in Chrome:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryKj5cK88faAwJd4av
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

[image content]

------WebKitFormBoundaryKj5cK88faAwJd4av--
```

My Web Api :

```
[Route(@"api/Storage/FileSas/Customers/{id:int}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFileSas(int id, string fileName, long? fileSize = 0, string contentType = null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
        this.ModelState.AddModelError("fileName", "File name i");

    if (!fileSize.HasValue || fileSize.Value > maxFileSize)
        this.ModelState.AddModelError("fileSize", "File size exceeded");

    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(this.ModelState);

    var serverUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SERVER_URL];
    var container = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[CONTAINER_NAME];

    SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    {
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write,
        SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-60),
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60),
    };

    CloudBlockBlob blobFile = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(Path.Combine("customers", id.ToString(), fileName));



    var exists = await blobFile.ExistsAsync();
    if (exists)
    {
        await blobFile.SnapshotAsync();
    }

    var signature = blobFile.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);

    return Content<string>(HttpStatusCode.Created, Path.Combine(serverUrl, container, blobFile.Name + signature));
}
```

My TypeScript file :

```
            context.Storage.getFileSas(customerId, file)
                .then((response: Interfaces.Result<string>) => {

                    let sasUrl = response.Data;

                    let formData = new FormData();

                    formData.append("file1", file, file.name);

                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
                        if (event.total > 0)
                            this.Progress(event.loaded * 100 / event.total);
                    };

                    xhr.onloadstart = function (e) {
                    }

                    xhr.onloadend = (e) => {
                        this.Progress(0);
                    }


                    xhr.open("PUT", sasUrl, true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-content-type', file.type);                
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-version', "2016-05-31");


                    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-meta-CustomerId', customerId);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-meta-UserId', context.User.User.Id.toString());
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-meta-UserName', context.User.User.Name);


                    xhr.send(formData);
                })
        })).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

File come from here :

```
 let fileInputElement1: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("file1");

 let file = fileInputElement1.files[0];
```

My HTML part : (i'm using knockout)

```
<form method="put" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="name" value="" id="file1" />
                <button data-bind="click:send"> Send</button>
</form>
```

If someone have an idea ? ...

Thank's in advance.

PS : sasUrl is like this : http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/customers/65143/test.jpg?sv=2016-05-31&sr=b&sig=s0671%2BLvCZTqyNfhlCthZW8KftjKyIMAlOT1nbsnlng%3D&st=2017-03-05T11%3A38%3A22Z&se=2017-03-06T12%3A38%3A22Z&sp=r&rsct=image%2Fjpeg

Comment: Instead of uploading form data, please read the file contents as array buffer and upload that array buffer. I wrote a blog post about this some time back that you may find useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/ (Please see Web Application section in the blog post). HTH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank's to  Gaurav Mantri, he point me to the right, here my modifications (only because i use typescript) :

```
  context.Storage.getFileSas(customerId, file)
            .then((response: Interfaces.Result<string>) => {

                let sasUrl = response.Data;

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
                    if (event.total > 0)
                        this.Progress(event.loaded * 100 / event.total);
                };

                xhr.onloadstart = function (e) {
                }

                xhr.onloadend = (e) => {
                    this.Progress(0);
                }


                let reader = new FileReader();

                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

                reader.onloadend = (event) => {
                        let target = <FileReader>event.target;

                        if (target.readyState == reader.DONE) {

                            var requestData = new Uint8Array(target.result);

                            xhr.open("PUT", sasUrl, true);
                            xhr.responseType = "blob";
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', file.name);
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type || 'application/octet-stream');
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-content-type', file.type || 'application/octet-stream');
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-version', "2016-05-31");


                            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-meta-CustomerId', customerId);
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-meta-UserId', context.User.Id.toString());
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-meta-UserName', context.User.Name);


                            xhr.send(requestData);
                        }
                    }
            })
    })).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Now i'll start to write a Promise to embedded this fonctionality.

PS : i didn't find the way to mark the Gaurav Mantri as answer so i create mine.
PS 2 : I'll like to put some +1 to Gaurav Mantri for the help... but i can't :/

Comment: Don't worry about it :). I am glad to hear that you're unblocked. Please accept your answer (it is completely fine + it will give you upvoting power!).